# Наследование конструкторов копирования и перемещения

Tags: c++, ооп

Как происходит наследование конструкторов копирования и перемещения?

```
class Parent {
public:
    Parent() = default;
    Parent(const Parent& other) {
        cout << "Копирования" << endl;
    }
    Parent(Parent&& other) {
        cout << "Перемещения" << endl;
    }
};

class Child : public Parent {
public:
};

int main() {
    Parent p;
    Child c;

    Parent p1(c);

    Child c1(c);
    Child c2(move(c));
}
```

Вывод:

```
Копирования
Копирования
Перемещения
```

Почему этот код работает без `using Parent::Parent`? Ведь конструкторы не наследуются.

```
class Parent {
public:
    Parent() = default;

    Parent(const Parent& other) {
        cout << "Копирования" << endl;
    }
    Parent(Parent&& other) {
        cout << "Перемещения" << endl;
    }
};

class Child : public Parent {
public:
    using Parent::Parent;
    Child(const Child& other) {
        cout << "Детский Копирования" << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Parent p;
    Child c;

    Parent p1(c);

    Child c1(c);
    Child c2(move(c));
}
```

Вывод:

```
Копирования
Детский Копирования
Детский Копирования
```

Почему не унаследовался конструктор перемещения? Я ведь не переопределил его внутри Child.

Также хочу отметить, что подобное поведение не относится к другим конструкторам, они ведут себя очевидно.

Comment: `Почему этот код работает без **using Parent::Parent?**` - вызывается конструктор по-умолчанию. `Почему не унаследовался конструктор перемещения?` - *Ведь конструкторы не наследуются.*

Comment: @AlexGlebe, не совсем понимаю, в конструкторе по умолчанию нет консольного вывода, а мы его наблюдаем

Comment: родительский класс пишет. Конструктор по-умолчанию сначала создаёт родителя, потом себя *по-умолчанию*.

Comment: @AlexGlebe, но почему не унаследовался конструктор перемещения при явном указании using Parent::Parent?

Comment: при создании объекта сначала конструктор базового инициализирует **свои** базовые переменные, потом вызывается конструктор предка и он также работает со **своими** переменными. Базовый класс не может инициализировать переменные предка, потому-что он его не знает и этих предков может быть очень много и разных.

Comment: @AlexGlebe, возможно "потомок", а не "предок"? Если в вашем комментарии нет ошибки, что тогда такое "базовый" класс?
Все равно нет понимания, почему при одном и том же using Parent::Parent, будет вызван или нет конструктор перемещения зависит от того, определен ли в дочернем классе конструктор копирования.

Comment: лекция будет большая. будет время попробую ответить...

Comment: @AlexGlebe, быть может дадите ссылку на хороший ресурс, где раскрывается тема? Нахожу в основном поверхностные статьи, в которых говорится, что конструкторы вызываются в порядке наследования классов от предков к потомкам...

Comment: Оставшиеся вопросы: - Удаляются ли, и если да, то почему унаследованные конструкторы копирования или перемещения при явном определении одного из них в дочернем классе; - Каким образом при отсутствии конструктора перемещения вызывается конструктор копирования при перемещающей инициализации, он ведь ожидает ссылку на объект, а мы передаем rvalue, в обычных функциях это приводит к ошибке; - Почему при объявлении Child c(Child(25)) (представим, что определен конструктор, принимающий int) вызывается только конструктор с int? Какая-то оптимизация? (Я ожидал еще вызов конструктора копирования)

Comment: `Child c(Child(25))` в новых версиях стандарта языка обязывает **не** создавать лишний временный объект и не вызывать конструктор копирования.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конструкторы копирования/перемещения и операторы присваивания не обладают свойством универсальности для наследуемого класса. Например, конструктор наследуемого класса сначала вызывает конструктор базового, затем инициализируются все новые элементы нового класса. И наследование для этих функций не предусмотрено. Так как у этих классов разное количество личных элементов, не говоря уже о том, что базовых классов тоже может быть много.
При отсутствии декларации конструкторов в классе создаются эти элементы компилятором по-умолчанию. А при декларации например одного конструктора копирования, конструктор перемещения по-умолчанию компилятором не создаётся. И программист должен сам написать все эти функции.

В первом примере :

```cpp
class Child : public Parent {
public:
};
```

сначала вызывается конструктор предка `Parent` затем инициализируются личные поля класса `Child`. И фактически это выглядит как такое объявление :

```cpp
class Child : public Parent {
public:
  Child() : Parent() {}
  Child(Child const & x) : Parent ( x ) {}
  Child(Child && x) : Parent ( std::move(x) ) {}
};
```

Вот такой класс :

```cpp
class Child : public Parent {
public:
    using Parent::Parent;
} ;
```

будет использовать все конструкторы предка **кроме** копирования/перемещения + будут добавлены *автоматически* конструкторы копирования/перемещения.

Во втором примере :

```cpp
class Child : public Parent {
public:
    using Parent::Parent;
    Child(const Child& other) {
        cout << "Детский Копирования" << endl;
    }
};
```

запись `using Parent::Parent;` создаёт собственные конструкторы для нового класса, используя вызов базового, **кроме** копирования/перемещения.

Объявление собственной функции копирования `Child(const Child& other)` отключает свойство компилятора и он не объявляет все эти функции сам, а программист должен сам все эти функции написать индивидуально. По-этому у вас не будет конструктора перемещения и операторов присваивания.